# Why does my python socket get 404 error?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, networking, web

```
socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect(("www.groupon.com", 80))
file = socket.makefile('r', 0)
file.write("GET " + "/coupons"  + " HTTP/1.0\n\nHost: " + "www.groupon.com" + "\n\nConnection: close\n\n")
buff = file.readlines()
```

Server Response

> GET https://www.groupon.com/coupons
>   HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Server: AkamaiGHost Mime-Version:
>   1.0 Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 200 Expires: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 17:49:11 GMT Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 17:49:11 GMT Connection:
>   close
>
> Invalid URL
>
> ## Invalid
>   URL
>
> The requested URL "/coupons", is invalid.
>
> Reference #9.bf254b8.1423331351.64ef899d

This happens to other websites too: I can only get response from index page.

What's wrong with my socket?

Comment: I'm using \n\n instead of \r\n. Because if I do that I get 404 error for every page.

Comment: Why not add that comment as answer to you own question. You might even accept your  own answer then.

Comment: I mean I get error either way.

Comment: What happens if you just do `... "GET watch?v=MsFohjWLKdI\r\n"`?

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Anyways `\n\n` is wrong and should be `\r\n` .

Answer (score 0):

> **What's wrong with my socket?**

Nothing. You approach the problem with too low-level tools.

Test case:

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect(("www.groupon.com", 80))
file = socket.makefile('r', 0)
file.write("GET " + "/coupons"  + "HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " + "www.groupon.com" + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n")
buf = file.readlines()
print buf
```

Response:

```
['HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\n', 'Server: AkamaiGHost\r\n', 'Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n', 'Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 19:17:53 GMT\r\n', 'Content-Type: text/html\r\n', 'Content-Length: 218\r\n', 'Expires: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 19:17:53 GMT\r\n', '\r\n', '<HTML><HEAD>\n', '<TITLE>Request Timeout</TITLE>\n', '</HEAD><BODY>\n', '<H1>Request Timeout</H1>\n', "The server timed out while waiting for the browser's request.<P>\n", 'Reference&#32;&#35;2&#46;63d77a5c&#46;1423336673&#46;0\n', '</BODY></HTML>\n']
```

Accessing `http://www.groupon.com/coupons` with a normal browser does redirect you to `httpS://...`. The error message "The server timed out while waiting for the browser's request" indicates that the web application waited for some client-triggered event that did not occur (likely some request triggered through JavaScript). In any case, your low-level approach does not just like that resemble the behavior of a browser. A browser does complex things, and the implementation of the HTTP protocol is just one part of it.